# Que veut dire cette etymologie de « chavirer » par « passer par dessus la tête » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [ [Wiktionnaire :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chavirer) ] De l’occitan *cavira*, de [*cap*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cap) (« tête ») et [*virar*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/virar) (« tourner »), littéralement « passer par dessus la tête ».

Qu'est-ce exactement qui passe par dessus la tête ?

La page ci-dessus contient une image où quelqu'un transporte un canoë/kayak sur sa tête après qu'il se soit retourné, mais je ne suis pas certain de savoir si cette phrase explicite l'étymologie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La photo montre un esquif renversé ; on peut dire que la personne qui est en dessous est dessalée :

> CHAVIRER - 1687 provençal *cap virar* "tourner la tête (en bas)" <sup>1</sup>
>
> - ... pour un bateau, se retourner sur lui-même ; synonyme : *dessaler* (tomber, être plongé dans l'eau), *renverser, basculer.*
> - Se renverser. « Ses yeux chavirèrent » ; synonyme : *se révulser* et aussi *chanceler, vaciller*.
> - S’abîmer, sombrer. « Ainsi les nations les plus grandes chavirent » – V.Hugo

---

<sup>1 Extraits du petit Robert</sup>

Comment: Merci de votre réponse, comme toujours. Je vous prie de pardonner mon ignorance : 1. pourriez-vous expliciter ce qui exactement passe par dessus la tête ?

Comment: @Timere  ... le cul ! L'expression ***cul par-dessus tête*** veut dire que l'on a les fesses plus hautes que le nez, ce qui, avouons-le n'est ni élégant, ni confortable. -- N.B. : Cul n'a pas ici de connotation vulgaire, seulement triviale ou familière : on parle du cul d'une bouteille pour désigner l'endroit où on la pause... et vous  trouverez sur CNRTL moult usages qui sont corrects, mais à ne pas employer dans des endroits guindés.

Comment: Je vous remercie!